# Annotating Rails models that have Globalize3 translation tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, internationalization, annotate, globalize3

Is it possible to use the `annotate (2.4.1.beta)` gem to output `globalize3 (0.2.0)` translated properties in the models that they translate?

If I have a `Post` creation migration generated [like so](https://github.com/svenfuchs/globalize3#rails--310rc)

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.timestamps
    end
    Post.create_translation_table! title: :string, text: :text
  end
  def down
    drop_table :posts
    Post.drop_translation_table!
  end
end
```

and its corresponding class looking like

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :text
  translates :title, :text
end
```

since the `:title` and `:text` attributes are not in the `posts` table but in the `post_translations` table, when I run

```
$ annotate --position before
```

they are not included in the output for the `Post` model:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: posts
#    
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  created_at :datetime        not null
#  updated_at :datetime        not null
#
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
...
```

Is there any way to include these attributes without manually typing them in after every annotation generation?

Comment: Looks like [this has already been asked about](https://github.com/ctran/annotate_models/issues/11) directly to the annotate devs a while back when Globalize was on version 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, unfortunately the answer to this question is no, there is no way to include Globalize translation attributes in an annotation generation.  Will just need to keep monitoring development on [annotate's Github repo](https://github.com/ctran/annotate_models).